# Does the link function triggers when the model changes in a directive and on directives nested on it

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to understand the [angular-weekly-scheduler module](https://github.com/fmaturel/angular-weekly-scheduler/blob/master/dist/js/ng-weekly-scheduler.js) in order to use it in my app. It consists on a main directive (notice the `Add new item` button below it too)

```
     <weekly-scheduler class="scheduler"
                      items="model.items"
                      on-change="demo.doSomething"
                      on-delete="demo.doSomething"
                      options="model.options">
      <div class="srow">{{::$index + 1}}. {{item.label}}</div>
    </weekly-scheduler>

    <div class="pull-right">
      <button class="btn btn-success" role="button" ng-click="model.items.push({label: 'New Item'})">Add new item</button>
    </div>
```

[source of this html chunk](https://github.com/fmaturel/angular-weekly-scheduler/blob/master/app/index.html)

In the angular directive declaration in the javascript (in this [file](https://github.com/fmaturel/angular-weekly-scheduler/blob/master/app/ng-weekly-scheduler/js/directives/weekly-scheduler.js)) is set the templateUrl property

```
templateUrl: 'ng-weekly-scheduler/views/weekly-scheduler.html'
```

which is loaded in the `$templateCache` and it looks like this (notice the `inject` attribute directive in the `div` with the class `schedule-animate`, the `monthly-grid` and the `weekly-grid` elements directives:

```
<div class=labels>
    <div class="srow text-right">{{schedulerCtrl.config.labels.month || \'Month\'}}</div>
    <div class="srow text-right">{{schedulerCtrl.config.labels.weekNb || \'Week number\'}}</div>
    <div class=schedule-animate ng-repeat="item in schedulerCtrl.items" inject></div>
</div>
<div class=schedule-area-container>
    <div class=schedule-area>
        <div class="srow timestamps">
            <monthly-grid class=grid-container></monthly-grid>
        </div>
        <div class="srow timestamps">
            <weekly-grid class=grid-container></weekly-grid>
        </div>
        <div class="srow schedule-animate" ng-repeat="item in schedulerCtrl.items">
            <weekly-grid class="grid-container striped" no-text></weekly-grid>
            <multi-slider index={{$index}}></multi-slider>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and inside the same directive javascript code , in its link function there is this $watchCollection:

```
scope.$watchCollection(attrs.items, onModelChange); //onModelChange is declared inside the same link function
```

When clicking on the `Add New item` button the model changes as its `ng-click` is set to `"model.items.push({label: 'New Item'})"` and its supposed to triggers the `onModelChange` function at first as the model changed on the `ng-click` is the same as in the `weekly-scheduler`'s directive `items` attribute which is the one watched by the above `$watchCollection` but what really happen is that the inject directive's link function triggers first but also the link functions of the `weekly-grid` and the `multi-slider` directives will trigger too respectively and after all that will finally be triggered the onModelChange function.

My question is: Does the link function triggers when the model changes in a directive? the `inject` directive has the same model on its `ng-repeat` attribute, so it's not much a surprise that its own link function will trigger but why do the other `weekly-grid` and the `multi-slider` link functions will trigger too as they are independent of the model? is it because their parent directive was updated in the UI?